# Flutter Injectable not injecting properly for web, despite working for the other platforms

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, injectable

The code compiles and works fine for `MacOS`, `iOS` (at least) but not for `Chrome`.

I'm using GoRouter to navigate between pages, and using Injectable to DI these pages and their dependencies.

- `Main` looks like this (besides setting up injectable stuff)

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget 
{
    const MyApp({super.key});

    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) 
    {
        var navigationService = getIt<NavigationService>();
        return MaterialApp.router
        (
            routerConfig: navigationService.goRouter,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange, colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange)),
        );
    }
}
```

That GoRouter is set up as follows somewhere in that NavigationService class:

```dart
_goRouter = GoRouter
(
    initialLocation: '/wordPairGenerator',
    navigatorKey: _homeNavigatorKey,
    routes:
    [
        StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack
        (
            builder: (context, state, navigationShell)
            {
                navigationContext.homePageNavigationShell = navigationShell;
                return GetIt.instance<HomePage>();
            },
            branches:
...
```

- That `HomePage` looks like:

```dart
@Injectable()
class HomePage extends UISection<HomePageView> 
{
    const HomePage(HomePageView view) : super(view);
}
```

and UISection is :

```dart
abstract class UISection<TView extends ViewBase> extends StatelessWidget
{
    @protected
    final TView view;
    
    const UISection(this.view);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => view(context);
}
```

- The `HomePageView`:

```dart
@Injectable()
class HomePageView extends ViewBase
{
    final HomePageViewModel _viewModel;
    HomePageView(this._viewModel);

    @override
    Widget call(BuildContext context)
    {
       ...
}
```

HomePageViewModel is also injected.
To explain, HomePageView declares UIElement stuff, which will be used by the HomePage in its build method. (just separating stuff, I have my reasons).

Now, all of this works well in `MacOS` and in `iOS` (at least), but fails on web.
I get this error when debugging the app on `chrome` :

> The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> HomePage$(dirty): NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function,
> such as null: 'this.view'
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:   HomePage$
>
> HomePage:file:///Users/home/Documents/Repos/Flutter%20Learning/favorits_app_2/lib/main.config.dart:67:42

It seems that it is failing resolving `view` in UISection constructor, means it is not injecting that HomePageView, am I wrong ?

so I have two questions :

1. Why it works normally on other platforms, as you can see:[image]
   and not on `chrome` as you can see:[image]
2. What's causing this and how to fix it?